# Android Java update custom Class object

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I'm using Java and here is my Class

```
public class OfflineData
{
    private String  name;
    private int     uniqueId;

    //constructor
    public OfflineData(String name, int id)
    {
        setName(name);
        setUniqueId(id);
    }

   //... getter and setter

}
```

In Class_A,  I'm adding adding values for OfflineData

```
OfflineData od1 = new OfflineData("OD1", 1);
OfflineData od2 = new OfflineData("OD2", 2);

offlineAdapter.add(od1);
offlineAdapter.add(od2);
```

OfflineAdapter class looks like:

```
public class OfflineAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<OfflineData>
{
    public OfflineAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<OfflineData> offlineList)
    {
        super(context, 0, offlineList);
    }
}
```

Now in Class_B, I want to update value for id 1 from OD1 to OD4 (for forever, until, I change it again)

Adding more code from OfflineAdapter class

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    //Get the data for the item at this position
    OfflineData offlineData = getItem(position);
    //check if the view is being reused, otherwise inflate it
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.offline_listview,parent,false);
    }

    //get references to the UI elements to populate them
    name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameview);

    //populate the data
    name.setText(offlineData.getName());

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: What does `offlineAdapter.add` do? I suppose it adds to a list. If so, iterator the list, find the `OfflineData` instance(s?) whose *name* is `OD1` and update it.

Comment: @user7 I want to update name based on id... I tried but did not get any success

Comment: Can you add your attempt? You need to show the data structure inside `OfflineAdapter` to hold the `OfflineData` objects

Comment: OfflineAdapter has getView just like any Adapter class, where I'm adding referencing and setting data that's it @user7

Comment: @user7  I added code from OfflineAdapter class... see above "Adding more code from OfflineAdapter class"

Comment: I'm not sure adding *getView* method is relevant here. You have to show what `offlineAdapter.add(..)` does and where it adds.

Comment: add is the in-built function to add a particular record in an Adapter @user7

Comment: Ah.. I see okay..